# Invalid Cast Exception was unHandled MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

When I run the program I get this error:

> Invalid Cast Exception was unHandled

This is part of form for fill a database, and visual Studio marks the int cast as the error

```
MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1; database=gymne; Uid=root; pwd=0000000000;");
using (MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from Socios where Nombre like @pNombre AND Apellido like @pApellido", conectar))
{
     conectar.Open();
     sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pNombre", txtNombre.Text);
     sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pApellido", txtApellido.Text);
     int UsuarioExiste = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();//<----"error here" 
     if (UsuarioExiste > 0)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("El Socio ya existe!!", "No Guardado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *strongly* suspect, you parameterize your `LIKE` part in a wrong way. You need to use `%..%` at least to figure out you try to get values that includes those string. Like;

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pNombre", "%" + txtNombre.Text + "%");
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pApellido", "%" + txtApellido.Text + "%");
```

Don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling (in somewhere maybe in your code) `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

By the way, be aware, [`COUNT(*)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) returns [`BIGINT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) in MySQL and this type mapped with [`Int64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64) in .NET side. As Steve [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35009572/447156), you can parse this value instead of casting like;

```
int UsuarioExiste = int.Parse(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());
```

or you can define your `UsuarioExiste` as `long` which seems more consistent(?) I think.

```
long UsuarioExiste = (long)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: So I don't need to use AddWithValue, Just Add?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the ExecuteScalar that in MySql returns an Int64 not an Int32. So the invalid cast when you use an explicit cast

With a conversion your error should go away

```
 int UsuarioExiste = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());
```

[You are not alone](http://forums.asp.net/t/1337375.aspx?ExecuteScalar%20with%20MySQL) to fall in this problem

Of course everything that has been said in the answer from Mr Soner Gönül is still applicable and should be done ASAP.

Comment: thanks so much I didn't know how to apply the changes

Comment: I have shown an explicit conversion to an Int32 and this should be enough to correctly handle the number of rows returned by your query. The link shows another approach using a long variable and using a explicit cast

Comment: @Steve Yeah, explicit conversation from `long` to `int` exist actually and explicit casting is okey _unless_ `ExecuteScalar` returns bigger than `int.MaxValue` which seems quite hard for most of us :)